# How to get list of headers of a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` object in my dialog.

I need to access the horizontal headers of this table and put them into a `QStringList` object.

Despite intensive search, I could not find in Qt documentation how to get this list of headers.

Edit: The closest I've found anywhere is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104024143/https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12502), but it's dealing with `QTableWidget`, and the functions used aren't available for `QTableView`. Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to switch the object in question to a table widget.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, the only way I can figure out to do it as like this:

```
QStringList headers;
for(int i = 0; i < myTableView->model()->columnCount(); i++)
{
  headers.append(myTableView->model()->headerData(i, Qt::Horizontal).toString());
}
```

Honestly this still seems a lot more convoluted than it should have to be, but at least it works.

Comment: I think "a lot more convoluted than it should have to be" is the official motto of Qt's ItemView classes ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner haha I feel the exact same way, ListView isn't too bad but TableView is such a pain, and that's nothing compared to the TreeView

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it a bit, like so.  this is the python variation

```
items = []
for x in range(tbl.columnCount()):
    items.append(tbl.horizontalHeaderItem(x).text())
```

Comment: I had to use tbl.horizontalHeaderItem(x)->text() in C++